# How are blockchain keypair private keys hidden from miners, and how are they generated in the first place?

Tags: cryptography, blockchain

I don't know how blockchain keypairs are programmatically generated, and equally important - how they are able to verify their keypair using a private key to a remote server - while keeping their private key entirely private.

How are blockchain keypairs generated, and private keys kept hidden by the remote server that is able to authenticate your account with some type of signing?

Is a public key a random hash and a private key the hash that parented the public key? If not, how? And how do they stay hidden the target network?

I am using encryption references in my IDE but am unsure how to utilize them effectively with a blockchain network.

```
Private Declare Sub MD5Init Lib "cryptdll" (Context As MD5_CTX)
Private Declare Sub MD5Update Lib "cryptdll" (Context As MD5_CTX, ByVal strInput As String, ByVal lLen As Long)
Private Declare Sub MD5Final Lib "cryptdll" (Context As MD5_CTX)

Private Function CalcMD5(sEncryptString As String) As String
    Dim strBuffer As String
    Dim myContext As MD5_CTX
    Dim result As String
    Dim lp As Long
    Dim MD5 As String

    strBuffer = sEncryptString

    MD5Init myContext
    MD5Update myContext, strBuffer, Len(strBuffer)
    MD5Final myContext

    result = StrConv(myContext.digest, vbUnicode)

    For lp = 1 To Len(result)
        CalcMD5 = CalcMD5 & Right("00" & Hex(Asc(Mid(result, lp, 1))), 2)
    Next

End Function
```

Yes, that's VB Classic. I am old, cut me a break.

I expected to understand keypairs, but I actually had no idea how they worked this entire time.

Answer (score 1):

In Bitcoin, private keys are (or should) be randomly generated by your wallet software, which is ideally offline using a high source of entropy.

The cryptography used in Bitcoin is Elliptic Curve, specifically the [secp256k1](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1) curve. It is a form of [asymmetric/public key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography), where private keys are any valid value in a very huge set (incomprehensibly huge like 10^70), and the public keys can be deterministically calculated by multiplying the private key with the curve's generator point using [Elliptic Curve Point Multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication).

The private keys are used to sign transactions (the private key never leaves the wallet software and is not shared with anyone including nodes). This signature algorithm is called the [Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm). The signature of the data can be verified using the data itself and the public key. If the signature verification algorithm succeeds, it can be deduced that the private key corresponding to the public key was in fact used to sign the data, proving the owner of the private key produced the signature. This is important in Bitcoin because it authorizes the owner of the coins to spend them.